# Edge Detection using usb webcam

Tags: camera

Can I use [sobel edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) or [canny algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) to detect edges in my RPI.

Can any give me any link to how to accomplish this and what the prerequisites are for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to check out http://opencv.org/
It has that and a lot more.

[Here's](http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/step-3-install-softwares-for-webcam-and-computer-vision/) a link with information on how to install OpenCV on your RaspberryPi.

Comment: i have used this edge code found online ..i have logitech webcam .. i typed the code in python and ran and has no errors in the code .. but i am getting a blank dialog box .. i am not sure whether webcam is capturing the image or the problem with the code ..

Answer (score 0):

Strictly to the process of detecting edges you can use Sobel for straigh vertical or horizontal lines and Canny Edge Detector for general borders.

Here the related webpages:

[Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html)

[Sobel](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html)